# Show existence of preimage under $P(x):=\sum\limits_{k=0}^na_kx^k$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, solution-verification, continuity

> Let be $P:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with $P(x):=\sum\limits_{k=0}^na_kx^k$, $a_n\neq 0$ and $n$ odd. Show that each $y\in \mathbb{R}$ has a preimage.

**My approach:**

We notice that
$$
\sum\limits_{k=0}^na_kx^k=x^n\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}a_kx^{-n+k}+a_n\right).
$$
Further, $\lim\limits_{j\to\infty}\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}a_kj^{-n+k}+a_n\right)=a_n\neq0$ and $\lim\limits_{j\to\infty}\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}a_k(-j)^{-n+k}+a_n\right)=a_n\neq0$ because each of the first $n-1$ summands is a zero sequence.

If $a_n>0$, convergence guarantees the existenc of two $j_0,j_1\in\mathbb{N}$ with
\begin{align*}
&\frac{a_n}{2}<\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}a_kj^{-n+k}+a_n\right)<\frac{3a_n}{2},\text{ for all }j>j_0\\
&\frac{a_n}{2}<\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}a_k(-j)^{-n+k}+a_n\right)<\frac{3a_n}{2},\text{ for all }j>j_1.
\end{align*}
Next,
\begin{align*}
&\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}a_kj^{k}>j^n\frac{a_n}{2}\\
&(-j)^n\frac{a_n}{2}>\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}a_k(-j)^{k}, ~<\text{-sign flips because }n\text{ is odd}.
\end{align*}
We have that $\lim\limits_{j\to \infty}j^n\frac{a_n}{2}=\infty$ and $\lim\limits_{j\to \infty}(-j)^n\frac{a_n}{2}=-\infty$ so for an arbitrary $y\in\mathbb{R}$ we can find two $i_1,i_2\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $P(i_1)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}a_k(-i_1)^{k}<y$ and $P(i_2)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}a_ki_2^{k}>y$. As $P$ is a continuous function over an interval we can apply the intermediate value theorem which guarantees the existence of a preimage $x$ of $y$ with $i_1<x<i_2$.

If $a_n<0$, then we proceed in a similar way. Finally, each $y\in\mathbb{R}$ must have a preimage.

---

Is this correct?

Comment: Standard easy argument: $P(x) \to \infty$ as $ x \to \infty$ and $P(x) \to -\infty$ as $ x \to -\infty$ if $a_n >0$ By Intermediate Value Property of continuous functions the result follows. Simialr argument when $a_n <0$.